# Inconsistent results when type punning uint64_t with union and bit-field

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, unions, type-punning

I am using an anonymous `struct` in `union` as follows:

```cpp
using time64_t = uint64_t;
using bucket_t = uint64_t;

union clock_test {
    time64_t _time64;

    struct {
        bucket_t _bucket5 : 10;     // bucket：5  1024
        bucket_t _bucket4 : 8;      // bucket：4  256
        bucket_t _bucket3 : 6;      // bucket：3  64
        bucket_t _bucket2 : 6;      // bucket：2  64
        bucket_t _bucket1 : 6;      // bucket：1  64
        bucket_t _bucket0 : 6;      // bucket：0  64
    };
};
```

If `bucket_t = uint64_t`, it works as expected, but with `using bucket_t = uint16_t` or `uint32_t`, I get puzzling results.

I use the same test code for all cases:

```cpp
clock_test clk;
clk._time64 = 168839113046;
```

For `bucket_t = uint64_t`, `clk` is:

```c
_bucket5   342  // unsigned __int64
_bucket4    26  // unsigned __int64
_bucket3    38  // unsigned __int64
_bucket2    15  // unsigned __int64
_bucket1    29  // unsigned __int64
_bucket0     2  // unsigned __int64
```

For `bucket_t = uint32_t`, `clk` is:

```c
_bucket    342  // unsigned int
_bucket4    26  // unsigned int
_bucket3    38  // unsigned int
_bucket2    15  // unsigned int
_bucket1    39  // unsigned int
_bucket0     0  // unsigned int
```

For `bucket_t = uint16_t`, `clk` is:

```c
_bucket5    342 // unsigned short
_bucket4    152 // unsigned short
_bucket3     15 // unsigned short
_bucket2     39 // unsigned short
_bucket1      0 // unsigned short
_bucket0      0 // unsigned short
```

---

...
use vscode + clang, See this issue clearly
[image]

Comment: In C++ don't use union (they really have a lot of issues), use std::variant

Comment: I don't understand where this output came from. What code are you actually running?

Comment: The standard says "This is Undefined Behaviour". You cannot access any member of a union except the one that was last written to, regardless of any bitfields.

Comment: Bitfields have several portability problems. One if that we don't know if `_bucket5` will be the first or last 10 bits of the struct. Another one is what happens when the bits don't add up with the underlying type. Some compilers will split `_bucket4` between two uint16_t, others will not.

Comment: Also, don't use anonymous structs if you want to create portable programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get inconsistent results is that bit-field members are normally not packed.
The type of the member matters, and may impact padding:

```cpp
// 168839113046 in binary
// type punned with bucket_t = unsigned short (assuming 16-bit)
00100111 01001111 10011000 01101001 01010110
  |    |   |    | |      |       |         |
  |    |   |    | |      |       01 01010110 // _bucket5 = 342
  |    |   |    | |      | ######            // padding to 16-bit bounds
  |    |   |    | 10011000                   // _bucket4 = 152
  |    |   001111                            // _bucket3 = 15
  |    | ##                                  // padding to 16-bit bounds
  100111                                     // _bucket2 = 39
...                                          // _bucket1 = 0
                                             // _bucket0 = 0
```

Whenever the compiler can't fit another bit-field member into the same 16-bit object, it inserts padding and puts it into the next one.
This changes the values you read, because you're reading bits at different positions. If your bit-field members all had a 64-bit type, this wouldn't happen.

### Non-Standard and Undefined Behavior

That being said, your code is just not valid C++.

1. anonymous structs are not standard C++; they only work because of a GCC compiler extension
2. the layout and alignment of bit-field members is completely implementation-defined, so you might not get the same results with different compilers
3. using `union` for type punning like this is undefined behavior; you can only access the active member of the union, with some exceptions

To get consistent results, use shifts and masks:

```cpp
time64_t data = 168839113046;
(data >>  0) & ((1u << 10) - 1)     // = 342
(data >> 10) & ((1u <<  8) - 1)     // = 26
(data >> 18) & ((1u <<  6) - 1)     // = 38
// ...
```

This will give you consistent results everywhere. It works by shifting the `data` to the right, and then using the bitwise AND operator to mask out the lowest N bits.

Comment: thank you very much! I try using #pragma pack(1) get clk same as uint64_t, thanks again.